# Class instance with .Net Session scope

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session

(MVC .Net App) Currently I use `HttpContext.Current.Session` to store some variables when a user logs in.  I am looking to see if a class instance with session scope is possible.  The instance will stay alive during the life time of session and I should be able to do get/set simply using the the class instance name like this anywhere in the code.

```
_myClass.FirmId = 1111;
```

Where should this line go so that it is executed only once when a session is created and `_myClass` variable is available throughout the code.

```
MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
```

May be it is a wishful thinking and not even possible.  Inputs?

Comment: Related: [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a Singleton class my friend, a singleton class is a class with only one instence means if i log in then i could only have 1 instece of that singleton class

now all you need is define a singleton class after the login action to autometically initialize the singleton class one per login

this link may help you start

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: How to make sure one instance per login?  Looking at the singleton model, it appears this could be one instance application wide, no?

Comment: @AllenKing you can be sure it will be one instance per login  use this method to save some of user info needed mostly in my app and i have checked it myself every login has its own instance

Comment: Singleton class uses static instance variable.  Static variables are shared application wide in .Net MVC applications.

Comment: @AllenKing static varables are sheared accross thye application but not in the case of singleton classes

Comment: Can you provide a reference for that?